# Adding command to context menu in Windows fails

Tags: windows, registry, contextmenu

I have (exported from my Registry):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.md]
@="markdownfile"
```

with a default value "markdownfile". I also have

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\markdownfile]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\markdownfile\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\markdownfile\shell\MarkAPL ==> HTML5]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\markdownfile\shell\MarkAPL ==> HTML5\command]
@="\"C:\\Programs\\..." \"%1\""
```

Yet "MarkAPL ==> HTML" does not show; instead it shows the filename in bold.

If I create ".aa" with a default value "markdownfile" then the command shows on any file with the extension ".aa". Clearly something else is having an impact here, but what?!

[image]
[image]

Comment: In my testing the menu shows. Not clear about the symptom "instead it shows the filename in bold", could you take a screen capture?

Comment: While taking the screenshots I realized that in Wiindows Explorer the contect menu show "Open" while in Total Commander (my tool of choice) it shows the filename.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3VhiTAx8vLYay1YTXl0b3RPXzg

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3VhiTAx8vLYYU8xZXRIcTdhak0

Comment: please edit your question and post your screenshot here.

Comment: How? As far as I know I cannot upload files to Stackflow?!

Comment: So the 2nd issue is not a real issue, right? it is the "MarkAPL ==> HTML" does not show. What is your OS version?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue on another PC without Total Commander?

Comment: I am on Windows 10. I cannot reproduce it on any other PC, with or without TotalCommander. I cannot even reproduce it on my PC with any other file extension than ".md". 

I believe now that it has to do with a Markdown editor called WriteMonkey. I believe (but cannot prove it) that the trouble started after I deinstalled WriteMonkey.

Comment: Posted as answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that when a user chooses "Start files with this extension with that application" from the Windows Explorer then sometimes - but by no means always - that takes precedence over the mechanism I tried to use.

After deleting the offending Registry entries it worked:

HKEY_USERS...\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.md\OpenWithList...